# Manage tag with django-select2

Tags: javascript, python, django, jquery-select2

We use `django-select2` for a project at work for managing tags. So now we use like this:

```
tags = ModelSelect2MultipleField(queryset=Tag.objects, required=False)
```

So it only works for existing tags, But it would be closer to the model stackoverflow and if the tag does not exist it adds, I found this link [Tagging with AJAX in select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229768/tagging-with-ajax-in-select2) which allows to manage side js, I'd like to know if it is possible to use an option in django-select2 to add it to the generated js. I would also like to know if instead of using the id it is possible to use a different field and side views in a get_form_kwargs I make a get_or_create.

Thanks

Comment: This is a new enhancement - https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/issues/33. This is on TODO list but I cannot promise about the timeline. I would really appreciate if someone can lend a help regarding this.

Comment: You could have a look at `django-select2-forms` with the `js_option` parameter. Mixed with http://stackoverflow.com/a/14841968/186202 it should be a good start. Or you can make a PR on `django-select2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applegrew make a new release that implements the management of tags with the tag created if it does not exist in the table. So use AutoModelSelect2TagField:

```
from django_select2 import AutoModelSelect2TagField


class TagChoices(AutoModelSelect2TagField):
    queryset = Tag.objects
    search_fields = ['name__icontains']

    def get_model_field_values(self, value):
        return {'name': value }


class SimpleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = TagChoices(required=False)
```

Here is a small example of using.

Comment: AutoModelSelect2TagField has been replaced by ModelSelect2TagWidget -https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.ModelSelect2TagWidget

Comment: `from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2TagWidget`

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me with `django-select2==7.1.1`

```
#models.py

from django.db import models


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(('Name'), max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)

#forms.py

from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2TagWidget


class ArticleTagSelect2TagWidget(ModelSelect2TagWidget):
"""
Widget class for auto populate, edit & add tags.
"""
queryset = Tag.objects.all()
search_fields = ('name__icontains',)

@property
def empty_label(self):
    return 'Type in tags'

def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    '''Create objects for given non-pimary-key values. Return list of all names as name is the to_field_name.'''
    values = set(super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name))
    # This may only work for Tag, if Tag has title field.
    # You need to implement this method yourself, to ensure proper object creation.
    names = self.queryset.filter(**{'name__in': list(values)}).values_list('name', flat=True)
    cleaned_values = list(names)
    for val in values - set(list(names)):
        cleaned_values.append(self.queryset.create(name=val).name)
    return cleaned_values

class AddArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
    widget=ArticleTagSelect2TagWidget(data_view='dashboard:auto-json'),
    required=False, to_field_name='name',)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

`#views.py` AutoResponseView is overriden for making the ajax return name instead of id.

```
from django_select2.views import AutoResponseView


   class TagAutoResponseView(AutoResponseView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This method is overriden for changing id to name instead of pk.
        """
        self.widget = self.get_widget_or_404()
        self.term = kwargs.get('term', request.GET.get('term', ''))
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return JsonResponse({
            'results': [
                {
                    'text': self.widget.label_from_instance(obj),
                    'id': obj.name,
                }
                for obj in context['object_list']
                ],
            'more': context['page_obj'].has_next()
        })
```

Comment: In which views.py  should `TagAutoResponseView` be put? Is it `myapp.views`?

Comment: you can put in any views.py. you just have to reference the view in urls.py and call that url. Put in the app which suits your need.

Comment: I have put it in `myapp.views` now. How can I reference this view in `myapp.urls`? Like `path('', TagAutoResponseView, name='auto-json')`? What should actually be the first argument in `path`? Is it 'tags/auto.json'? Thanks for reply!

Comment: Unfortunately, after having the views and forms set, my `tags` field in the add form only shows '0 Items'. Not as similar as a normal select2 widget :(

Comment: I am very confused about why the Tags field shows '0 Items'? I have set the right QuerySet for Tag (i.e. Tag.objects.all()) and I am using django-taggit

Comment: you might start with debugging using the browsers xhr request area. look for the request fired while you click on the select box. see if the request is 200 or 404 or 500 and fix your url accordingly.