# Filtering with Select2 Ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery-select2, tagging

I am having a lot of trouble with the select2 plugin trying to get tagging (Auto Tokenization to work).  I am employing the same process as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14841968/2314341), but the issue is that although the words underline when they match, they do not filter.

I have read that it may be best to do this server side, but I can not come up with an efficient way to do that.

Any ideas/tips?

```
$('#tagging').select2({
        width: '100%',
        multiple: true,
        tokenSeparators: [",", ";"],
        tags: true,
        createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
          if ($(data).filter(function() {
            console.log(this.text);
            return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0;
          }).length===0) {
            return {id:term, text:term};
          }
        },
        ajax: {
          url: "/tags",
          dataType: "json",
          results: function(data, page) {
            return { 
              results: $.map( data, function(tag, i) { 
                return { id: tag.id, text: tag.keyword } 
              } )
            }
          }
        }
    });
```

I am using Ruby on Rails, if that matters.

Comment: full error? a JSfiddle with problem showcases would be nice

Comment: I am not getting an error at all.