# Get ng2-select2 selected item value on form submission

Tags: angular, jquery-select2, angular2-forms

I've tried the following code:

HTML:

```
<form #dropdownform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(dropdownform)">
  <select2 [data]="exampleData"></select2>
</form>
```

TypeScript:

```
this.exampleData= [...]
OnSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
  }
```

It shows an empty array in the console.

Answer (score 0):

> Note : Without `name` property you will never get any value on form.value , if you are using template-driven-form.

All you need to do is provide `name` property and `ngModel` :

```
<select2 name="select2_value" [data]="exampleData" ngModel></select2>
```

---

Now when you `console.log(form.value);`

You will get the value as `{ select2_value : 'selected_value' }`

Comment: not working, showing an error when I added two-way data binding : 'Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name:select2_value'

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr, please upvote and accpet the answer , if it was not helpful please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

select2 wants to data.id and data.text or you need to  define datatype this link may help you

[Tagging with AJAX in select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229768/tagging-with-ajax-in-select2)